# Lightning, "e.force:navigateToURL"

Tags: lightning, community

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                   urlEvent.setParams({
                       "url": '/xxx?zipCode=5555"
});
```

How to retrieve "zipCode" on the destination component ("xxx")?
I need a standard Lightning solution.

When I try to do this by `component.get("v.zipCode")`, the result is "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value from the window object using javascript below

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  // This is url query parameter
  var value = helper.getParameterByName(component , event, 'zipCode');
  // Set the value, assumes you have created attribute "attributename" in your markup
  component.set("attributename", value);
}
```

Helper function

```
getParameterByName: function(component, event, name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
   var url = window.location.href;
   var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");
   var results = regex.exec(url);
   if (!results) return null;
   if (!results[2]) return '';
   return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

I figured now the [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation.htm) component supports salesforce communities as well .

So a better way would be to use [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation.htm) as you can pass state and parameters and easily receive them .

Comment: Is there a standard Lightning solution?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation.htm .You can use lightning:navigation now instead of navigateToUrl component